# Apache Storm - Kinesis Spout throwing AmazonClientException backing off

Tags: apache-storm, amazon-kinesis

```
2016-02-02 16:15:18 c.a.s.k.s.u.InfiniteConstantBackoffRetry [DEBUG] Caught exception of type com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException, backing off for 1000 ms.
```

I tested GET and PUT using Streams and Get requests - both worked flawless. I have all 3 variants Batch, Storm and Spark. Spark - used KinesisStreams - working Batch: Can you Get and Put - working Storm: planning to use KinesisSpout library from Kinesis. It is failing with no clue.

```
final KinesisSpoutConfig config = new KinesisSpoutConfig(streamname, zookeeperurl);
config.withInitialPositionInStream(ipis);
config.withRegion(Regions.fromName(regionName));
config.withCheckpointIntervalMillis(Integer.parseInt(checkinterval));
config.withZookeeperPrefix("kinesis-zooprefix-" + name);

System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", key);
System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", keysecret);
SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider scp = new SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider();
final KinesisSpout spout = new KinesisSpoutConflux(config, scp, new ClientConfiguration());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Storm Logs:

```
2016-02-02 16:15:17 c.a.s.k.s.KinesisSpout [INFO] KinesisSpoutConflux[taskIndex=0] open() called with topoConfig task index 0 for processing stream Kinesis-Conflux
2016-02-02 16:15:17 c.a.s.k.s.KinesisSpout [DEBUG] KinesisSpoutConflux[taskIndex=0] activating. Starting to process stream Kinesis-Test
2016-02-02 16:15:17 c.a.s.k.s.KinesisHelper [INFO] Using us-east-1 region
```

I don't see "nextTuple" getting called.

My Versions:

- storm = 0.9.3
- kinesis-storm-spout = 1.1.1

Comment: 1: Overwritten 
public class KinesisSpoutMine extends KinesisSpout
overridden "open"
ad added
System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", "...key...");
System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", "...keysecret...");
super.open(..)

Comment: Outstanding Issues:
1: 0 byte files in HDFS
2: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: message does not exist

Comment: 2016-02-03 02:25:02 c.a.s.k.s.KinesisShardGetter [DEBUG] KinesisShardGetter[shardId=shardId-000000000000] fetched 1 records from Kinesis (requested 10000).
2016-02-03 02:25:02 c.a.s.k.s.KinesisSpout [DEBUG] KinesisSpoutConflux[taskIndex=0] emitting record with seqnum 49558606788284125675005869972919011606055542508908183554 from shard shardId-00000000000
0.
2016-02-03 02:25:02 STDIO [ERROR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: message does not exist
2016-02-03 02:25:02 STDIO [ERROR] at backtype.storm.tuple.Fields.fieldIndex(Fields.java:78)
2016-02-03 02:25:02 STDIO [ERROR] at

Comment: Fixed: Implement IKinesisRecordScheme and set that class on KinesisSpoutConfig. config.withKinesisRecordScheme(new KinesisRecordSchemeMy());